# Cannot download through a link

Tags: applications, downloading

I have google play and app gallery (from Huawei). but whenever i need to download an app through a link it brings me directly to the Huawei Gallery and of course it is telling me the app is not available in my region. how can I solve the problem, I have a google account on my phone and the Huawei cloud account.

Comment: when I try to download it is asking if i want huawei app gallery or play store, even if i select play store it still brings me to huawei app gallery

Comment: Can you add on the question the phone model (what Huawei model) and Android version?

Comment: Huawei mate 20 X Android version 9

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Apps -> App Gallery -> Open by default, select "Ask every time" (or "Don't open in this app").
2. Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Apps -> Google Play Store -> Open by default, select "Always allow".

You find "play.google.com" in Other defaults or Supported links of App Gallery, remove it also (just in case).

Comment: I have a Huawei phone andthe settings are different:I have Apps < app launch.when i google under play store i cannot select open by default, it says that I have chosen to open this app by default sometimes